# How can I use Google's functions in a spreadsheet's script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, importxml

When I use a function such as `=importXml("http://www.google.com", "//a/@href")` in a Google Spreadsheet cell, it works just fine. However, when I try to use the same function in a script, it gives an error message.

My script has the following code:

```
function myFunction() {
  return importXml("http://www.google.com", "//a/@href");
}​
```

When I call the function from a cell by using `=myFunction()`, I get the following error:

> **error:** ReferenceError: "importXml" is not defined.

How can I use the `importXml` function in a script?

Comment: did you have a solution now?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the remark made by Barry, here's a link that explains the usage of XML in combination with Google Apps Script (GAS): [XML with GAS](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps-script/1dDWF55z9PA)

You *can* use the `importXML` formula in GAS, but you have to address it as a formula:

```
function myXML() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  cell.setFormula('=importXml("http://www.google.com", "//a/@href")');  
}
```

Reference: [setFormula](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range?hl=en#setFormulas)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible because `ImportXML` is a spreadsheet function and is not available in the Script Editor.

You would have to write a script to get the XML from the URL and then parse it manually.

What exactly are you trying achieve? (I am presuming that the Google Url and href elements are an example?)